# Arrow successfully parses some input not in default patterns

Tags: python, arrow-python

Given invalid input, arrow raises `ParserError`:

```
>>> arrow.get('abc')
ParserError: Could not match input to any of [u'YYYY-MM-DD', u'YYYY/MM/DD', u'YYYY.MM.DD', u'YYYY-MM', u'YYYY/MM', u'YYYY.MM', u'YYYY', u'YYYY', u'YYYY'] on 'abc'
>>> arrow.get('09-10-201')
ParserError: Could not match input to any of [u'YYYY-MM-DD', u'YYYY/MM/DD', u'YYYY.MM.DD', u'YYYY-MM', u'YYYY/MM', u'YYYY.MM', u'YYYY', u'YYYY', u'YYYY'] on '09-10-201'
```

This shows all matching patterns that arrow had tried before raising the exception. However, occasionally, even when the input does not match any of these patterns, it silently converts it to an object:

```
>>> arrow.get('09-10-2017')
<Arrow [2017-01-01T00:00:00+00:00]>  # Succeeds with incorrect date
```

Is this explained by additional hidden parse patterns provided by my system locale? If so, why would it parse 2017 and leave out 09 and 10? If not, why did the parsing succeed?

Comment: Guessing from the error messages - when you feed it `'09-01-2017'`, it's matching `2017` as being of the form `'YYYY'` and converting just that to a date. The date format you use, `'DD-MM-YYYY'` (or `'MM-DD-YYYY'`) isn't included in the list of options.

Comment: If your date format is consistent with what you're testing, you could use `arrow.get('09-10-2017', ['DD-MM-YYYY'])` (or `arrow.get('09-10-2017', ['MM-DD-YYYY'])`)

Comment: @asongtoruin Yeah I am trying to make arrow *raise* an exception, not allow ambiguous date formats like `MM-DD-YYYY` or `DD-MM-YYYY`. And it would seem to be all cases except this one that it does not raise a parser error.

Comment: It seems to raise an exception if you provide 'accepted' formats as an argument - e.g. `arrow.get('09-10-2017', ['YYYY-MM-DD'])` throws an error. It's a little tedious, but you could prepare a list of acceptable formats and feed it like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrow uses regex to match a given string with a date format.

For example:

```
arrow.get('aaa2012-01-21aa')
```

is accepted as input

```
<Arrow [2012-01-21T00:00:00+00:00]>
```

because it matches the format `YYYY-MM-DD` which internally was converted to a regex of the form  `'(?P<YYYY>\d{4})-(?P<MM>\d{2})-(?P<DD>\d{2})'`  and this regex capture the case.

Your input has a match only for `YYYY` and the rest of the string being discarded.

For raising an error and forcing a specific format, the advice given  by   @asongtoruin  is  a very good one.

Comment: Looks to be the case :(